# Can not install ubuntu server VMs

Tags: server, system-installation

For some reason I can not load ubuntu VMs after I signed in I do not know why but this option is unavaliable for me. Can you plaese help me with solving such a problem?

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1393863/edit) to clearly describe the procedure you are following. A link to any instructions you are following would be helpful, as would complete output showing failures or errors.